# How to draw mathematical diagrams in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, latex

Mathematician here trying to create some diagrams for my undergraduate thesis. I'
Long story short, I'd like to be able to create something like this.

[image: example]
I'm trying to work with inkscape and want to be able to export it into a latex file.

Any helpful tips for a complete beginner? I'm especially puzzled by how to get the angles for my vectors right and all the correct fonts.

Comment: could you please show us what you have tried and where you are getting stuck? As-is, your question is pretty broad. Thanks!

Comment: What makes a correct font? Same font name? Same size-relations?

Answer (score 9):

Your question is really very broad, but if an animation would help with the the construction of such a diagram, then here it is.  Here I use the Rectangle tool, a skew transform, the Bézier tool, fills, strokes, and arrow markers. These are all fairly basic functions in Inkscape.

[image]

The rest is just typing. Use the Character map to find symbols such as Phi, and copy and paste it into Inkscape. The font looks like Times.

The best way to learn the basics is to look for tutorials on youtube. There are thousands of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Inkscape extension [WriteTex](https://writetex.tk/) to directly write math using LaTeX code.

Comment: Can you please how one has to use this software to solve the given issue?

Comment: @Kurt, the extension is meant for writing LaTeX text and math (helps a lot for greek letters and formulas) inside Inkscape. You still have to do the drawing as explained in Billy Kerr's answer.